# Computing an approximate root of a two-dimensional monotone function

Tags: approximation-algorithms, time-complexity, na.numerical-analysis, computing-over-reals, fixed-points

Let $f$ be a [Lipschitz-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) function from the square $[-1,1]^2$ to itself, satisfying the following conditions:

- For all $y\in [-1,1]$:    $~~~~f(-1,y)_1\leq 0\leq f(1,y)_1$, and $f(x,y)_1$ is monotonically-increasing with $x$.
- For all $x\in [-1,1]$:    $~~~~f(x,-1)_2\leq 0\leq f(x,1)_2$, and $f(x,y)_2$ is monotonically-increasing with $y$.

The [Poincare-Miranda theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem) guarantees that $f$ has a *root* -- a point $(x,y)$ for which $|f(x,y)|=0$.

I am interested in computing an *$\epsilon$-root* of $f$ -- point $(x,y)$ for which $|f(x,y)|\leq \epsilon$. The number of function evaluations should be polynomial in $\log_2(1/\epsilon)$ --- the binary representation of $\epsilon$ <sub>(where the Lipschitz constant is considered a fixed parameter)</sub>. **Is it possible?**

---

To motivate the question, here are some related results.

1. If the function is one-dimensional (from $[-1,1]$ to itself), then the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) can be used to find $\epsilon$-root of $f$ using $O(\log(1/\epsilon))$ evaluations. This is true even without the monotonicity conditions.
2. Without the monotonicity conditions, finding an $\epsilon$-root is computationally equivalent to finding an $\epsilon$-fixed-point. It is [known](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0885064X89900174?via%3Dihub) that finding an $\epsilon$-fixed-point in two dimensions might require $\Omega(1/\epsilon)$ evaluations, that is, the number of evaluations is exponential in the binary representation of $\epsilon$. (I [asked about it in this cs.SE post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/159373/1342).)

Can the monotonicity condition make the two-dimensional problem polynomial in $\log(1/\epsilon)$?

I am also interested in references to other conditions,  similar to monotonicity, that make the two-dimensional problem polynomial in $\log(1/\epsilon)$.

Comment: Is $f(-1,y)\leq 0\leq f(1,y)$ supposed to be $f(-1,y)_1 \leq 0\leq f(1,y)_1$?

Comment: Shouldn't the running time also depend on the Lipschitz constant?

Comment: This probably answers the question: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11561071_78

Comment: @mathworker21 yes, fixed.

Comment: @ChaoXu yes, the runtime also depends on the Lipschitz constant. For simplicity, I assumed that it is a fixed constant. The paper you linked to is very interesting, but it considers functions from a 2-dimensional array to $\mathbb{R}$, not to to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Also, the property of monotonicity is defined differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with $O\left(\log^2(1/\epsilon)\right)$ function evaluations.

We write $f = (f_1,f_2)$, so in your notation, e.g. $f_1(x,y) := f(x,y)_1$. By replacing $f_1$ with $(x,y) \mapsto f_1(x,y)+\epsilon x$ and $f_2$ with $(x,y) \mapsto f_2(x,y)+\epsilon y$ (at the unimportant cost of changing $\epsilon$ to, say, $4\epsilon$), we may assume that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are *strictly* increasing.

The key is that the monotonicity assumptions imply that the function $g : [-1,1] \to [-1,1]$ given by $$g(y) := f_2(x_y,y)$$ is continuous, where $x_y$ is the unique solution to $f_1(x_y,y) = 0$ (which exists since $f_1$ is strictly increasing and has $f_1(-1,y) \le 0 \le f_1(1,y)$).

Indeed, it suffices to show that $x_{y_n} \to x_y$ whenever $y_n \to y$ (since $f_2$ is continuous). If, for contradiction, there were some $\delta > 0$ and some subsequence $(y_{n_k})_k$ of $(y_n)_n$ with $x_{y_{n_k}} > x_y+\delta$ for all $k$, then $$0 = f_1(x_{y_{n_k}},y_{n_k}) \ge f_1(x_y+\delta,y_{n_k}) \to f_1(x_y+\delta,y) > f_1(x_y,y) = 0,$$ where the limit is taken as $k \to \infty$. The similar argument works for the case of some $\delta > 0$ and some subsequence $(y_{n_k})_k$ with $x_{y_{n_k}} < x_y-\delta$ for all $k$.

Now that we know $g(y)$ is continuous, the bound $O\left(\log^2(1/\epsilon)\right)$ follows relatively straightforwardly from the bisection method. Indeed, for any fixed value of $y$, the bisection method allows us to approximate $x_y$ up to an additive error of $\pm \epsilon$, with $O\left(\log(1/\epsilon)\right)$ function evaluations. Because $f_2$ is Lipschitz, this allows us to calculate $g(y)$ up to an additive error of $\pm O(\epsilon)$, which is sufficient to make the bisection method applied to the one-dimensional function $g$ work as needed, with $O\left(\log(1/\epsilon)\right)$ function evaluations of $g(y)$.

Comment: Thanks! I am working on a paper that proves a slightly more generalized result (without the continuity condition), and some applications. I will be happy to add you as a co-author. By what name can I add you?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Wow, thank you, I am honored. My name is Chester Lawrence (I have no affiliations nor grants to thank).

Comment: I sent you a draft - did you get it?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I just checked my spam and it was there. I'll look now.